# Mysql query to find out which id is having both french and german

Tags: mysql

[image]

what will be the query to find out which id is having both languages french and german?

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding about what an "id" is.

Comment: Let's step back - What are you trying to accomplish (at a higher level)?

Comment: @Juhana these are students id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this statement:

```
SELECT id
FROM st 
where name in ('german','french')
Group by id
having Count(*)=2
```

You should rename the column `id` in `student_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT st1.id
FROM st as st1 
JOIN st as st2 ON st1.id=st2.id AND st2.sname='german'
WHERE st1.sname='french'
```